# How to remove sysadmin from sa login in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement wherein I need to remove sysadmin server role from sa login.

I created 1 more user and gave the sysadmin role to the user.

When I uncheck sysadmin from sa login it throws an error.

Cannot use the special principal sa error 15405.

Can anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: That's a rash requirement, MS have had bugs where upgrades (SPs, new versions) have failed if SA login is removed. A more normal practice is to disable the SA login - maybe you could double check the requirement.

Comment: Well, actually, you must give `sa` long, forgettable/non-rememberable password, pack it in an envelope, and put it in the safe. And for everyday administrative tasks, you must create a different account.

Comment: You can throw away the password.  A Windows Admin can always change it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 6):

You cannot remove sysadmin from this login. The login with [sid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-sid-transact-sql) 0x01 (generally named "sa") is always sysadmin.

I assume that you have disabled sa in the first place, btw.

How about [renaming sa to some other name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103825/does-sa-account-need-to-be-called-sa-or-can-i-rename-it-safely)?

Comment: Or disabling it :)

Comment: Absolutely, Shanky! That was implied in my thinking. I assumed that the mere fact of sa being sysadmin (even if disabled) was the problem. I'll add a note on that in my answer! :-)

Comment: Please don't rename `sa` for Mo64's reason in his comment.

Comment: I remember the timeframe where there were som bugs with renamed sa. I believe it was around 2005 (or was it even 7.0/2000)? I haven't seen any bugs related to this for at least 10 years. It doesn't mean they don't exist, but I have a feeling that this might be one of those things that sticks even if not applicable anymore...

Answer (score 0):

I have a better approach:

1. Change the sysadmin password
2. Give your sysadmin user with the new password to your new DBA

Answer (score -1):

You cannot drop the sa login and change the permissions of sa.But you can change its password, rename and disable it.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. While your answer might be valid, it does help if there is some context is given or material referenced. Please have a  look at [answer].

Comment: Also, please don't post answers that are more or less duplicates of existing ones (Tibor's answer).